# Angular2 email validation pattern not working

Tags: angular

Form:

```
    <div class="group">
      <label for="email" class="label">Email Address</label>
      <input id="email" type="text" class="input" name="email" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
             #email="ngModel" required>
      <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
        <div [hidden]="!email.errors.required">
          email invalid
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I tried using regex pattern but it is not woking, it doesnt shows any error and user is created without valid email address. I used this pattern from other angular2 email validation answers from stackoverflow.

Comment: You might want to consider https://hackernoon.com/the-100-correct-way-to-validate-email-addresses-7c4818f24643 and https://hackernoon.com/how-to-reduce-incorrect-email-addresses-df3b70cb15a9

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(this.email)){
   console.log('valid email');
}else{ 
   console.log('invalid email');
}
```

Comment: It is working for me. Try trimming your email must have spaces or anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input id="email" type="text" class="input" name="email" pattern="/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@']+)*)|('.+'))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/" [(ngModel)]="user.email"
```